Istio GKE ciphersuites
I want to add cipher suits for my istio gke setup. I have added the cipher suits in below pattern, but while testing it through ssllabs site, I cannot see the ciphers added.
Format:
 - hosts:
    - 'domain_name'
   
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      cipherSuites:
      - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256
      - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
      - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256

